# Number of element with specific class name after in an ajax result

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'd like to know the number of element with myclass as CSS name are in the value result

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Home/Index',
    type: 'POST',
    data: id : 5,
    success: function (data) {

        //get number of myclass here


    }
});
```

I tried this :
`$('.myclass', data).length;` but I get 0 all the time

**Update1**
*Output console :*

```
<div class="ui-widget myclass">
    <div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;"> 
        <p><span id="iconAlert" class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span> 
        <strong>Alert:</strong> Sample ui-state-error style.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to explain your question a little better and what does data look like ?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(data);` ?

Comment: @sje397 I added the output. I'd like to know id an element (div in this case) has `myclass` in the class of one of the elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you need to use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$(data).filter(".myclass");
```

Your current attempt is equivalent to `$(data).find(".myclass")` and since `find` looks at *descandants* it won't find any elements at the top level. `filter` on the other hand, will.

Comment: when I do `alert($(data).filter(".myclass"));` the message just [Object]

Comment: That's because it returns a jQuery object. If you are wanting to know how many elements it contains use the `length` property like you were doing before.

Comment: @Kris-I you should alert `$(data).filter(".myclass").length`